# Can I share the same setup across multiple mocks of the same type?

Tags: c#, moq

As the title says, can I make a Setup for one Mock and then somehow transfer it across multiple objects of the same type?

Let's say I am creating a `Mock<IProcessor>()`. I want to create multiple of these mock objects, but with the same setup (ie, all should have the same expectations, but there are several instances of them). It wouldn't make much sense for me to repeat the code multiple times - can I share the `ISetup` somehow?

Comment: Well, you could always use a `foreach` loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moq itself doesn't provide a facility for that, AFAIK.

But you can easily move your setup code to an extension method:

```
public static void MySetup(this Mock<IProcessor> mock)
{
    mock.<setup-whatever>
}
```

Then, in each location where you need it, you can do this:

```
...
var mock = new Mock<IProcessor>();
mock.MySetup();
...
```

Comment: possibly you mean `mock.MySetup()`